# cross site postMessage isn't picked up by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, postmessage

I have an iframe from itch.io embedded in my webpage. The iframe sends me a message via postMessage:

```
   //This gets send from a Unity WebGL game
   SendMessageToPage: function (text) {
      var convertedText = Pointer_stringify(text);
      // Pass message to the page
      window.parent.postMessage(convertedText, "*");
   }
```

The parent webpage (the website I have embedded the iframe in, so it should be the parent, right?) is supposed to pick it up with an Event Listener:

```
 <script>
    alert("Hello")  //<-This one fires
    
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event){ 
      alert("Hello from);
      if (event.origin != 'https://itch.io') { 
        alert("Unknown Source");
        return;
      }
      alert("received: " + event.data)
    });

</script>
```

Additionally I have a div element to receive the message

```
  <script>
        document.getElementById("WriteOut").addEventListener('message', function(e){ 
          document.getElementById("WriteOut").innerHTML="Got Something";
        });
  </script>
```

I can see that the message sent from itch appears in the console log, so I kinda suspect that I didn't configure the event listeners correctly. The message also only comes in long after the website has loaded (atm ~15sec after page opening), so it shouldn't be a problem with the listener not being loaded in.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? As far as I can tell I pass the right arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix / the real problem:
As the game was not running directly in iframe, window.parent did not address the window with the listener, but some window in between. changing it to

```
  //This gets send from a Unity WebGL game
   SendMessageToPage: function (text) {
      var convertedText = Pointer_stringify(text);
      // Pass message to the page
      window.top.postMessage(convertedText, "*");
   }
```

worked.